# Javascript in_array

Tags: javascript

In php this is a nice way of asking is a value is one of a few options

```
if( in_array($needle, [1,325,'something else']) ){
   //do your thing
}
```

But in the world of javascript is there an equiv. that doesn't require writing a bespoke function such as:

```
function inArray(needle, haystack) {
   var length = haystack.length;
   for(var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      if(typeof haystack[i] == 'object') {
         if(arrayCompare(haystack[i], needle)) return true;
      } else {
         if(haystack[i] == needle) return true;
      }
   }
   return false;
}
function arrayCompare(a1, a2) {
    if (a1.length != a2.length) return false;
    var length = a2.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (a1[i] !== a2[i]) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Use case of the above js bespoke function

```
if( inArray( somvar, [1,2,'something else']) ){
   do the javascript thing
}
```

FROM THE COMMENTS
this is the most accurate answer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

Comment: Whats wrong with [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)  and [Array.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)?

Comment: or `indexOf`? please add a question?

Comment: `[1,325,'something else'].indexOf($needle) > -1`

Comment: and [Array.prototype.findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)

Comment: ...actually, since you want a boolean result with a simple equality match, the forthcoming [Array.prototype.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) will make more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```
var data = ['Lorem', 'Ipsum', 'Sit']

var foundSit = data.find(function(item){
   return item == 'Sit';
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var needle = 325;

if( [1,325,'something else'].indexOf(needle) !== -1 ){
   //do your thing
};
```